# Find the surface area obtained by rotating $y= 1+3 x^2$ from $x=0$ to $x = 2$ about the $y$-axis

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the surface area obtained by rotating $y= 1+3 x^2$ from $x=0$ to $x = 2$ about the $y$-axis.

Having trouble evaluating the integral:

Solved for $x$:

- $x=0, y=1$
- $x=2, y=13$

$$\int_1^{13} 2\pi\sqrt\frac{y-1}3 \cdot \sqrt{1+\sqrt\frac{y-1}3'}^2\,dy$$

also tried it

$$\int_0^2 2\pi(1+3x^2)\sqrt{1+(6x)^2}\,dx$$

any input/help would be great thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt (rather, your first set up) is correct, since we are rotating the curve about the y-axis.

You can start by finding $$\left(\sqrt{\frac {y-1}3}\right)'$$

Comment: I solved the derivative 1/(2sqrt(3)*sqrt(y-1)).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I see what you did! Now, square the derivative. That will greatly simplify matters.